# Should I always compile Java code with latest javac compiler?

Tags: java, compilation, jvm, bytecode

I'm about to upgrade a tomcat installation from version 6.0 to version 8.5, and also upgrading the JVM from 6 to 8. Our java code is compiled with java 6 as for now.

I know that running java code on the latest JVM is always a good idea performance-wise (not to mention security-wise). In this way some code compiled with java 1.6 might run faster on JVM 8 compared to JVM 6.

But how about compilation? Does one gain anything by compiling code written in java 6 with a java 8 compiler (i.e. only java 6 features are used)? I.e. does code written with the intent of compiling with java 1.6 run faster on JVM 8 when the code is compiled with java 8 (targeted 8) and not java 6? Is the bytecode from java 8 optimized compared to java 6?

And regarding the target flag. Is anything gained by compiling java 6 code with a java 8 compiler targeted to java 6 (when the code is still to be run on JVM 6), compared to if the code was compiled with a java 6 compiler?

Comment: Java is compile, once, run anywhere. Once it's compiled, you don't need to re-compile it to take advantage of the latest JVM. You can take JAR for version 1.0.2 and run it on a Java 9 JVM and it will use all the latest optimisations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is anything gained by compiling java 6 code with a java 8 compiler targeted to java 6 compared to if the code was compiled with a java 6 compiler?

No.

There is absolutely no performance gain, since the java compiler don't perform *any* kind of optimization, not even obvious ones.

Any optimization that could be performed on the bytecode produced by `javac` is done by the JIT engine once your application is running.

Edit: Look at pveentjer comment, a few simple optimizations (e.g. constant resolution) are performed by javac. But i'm still confident that the answer regarding the differences between 6 and 8 is still "no".

Comment: There are not many optimizations applied by the Javac; but there are some:
http://pveentjer.blogspot.com.tr/2017/01/final-static-boolean-jit.html

Comment: I've never noticed that, I'm wondering when it was introduced.

Answer (score 0):

As you already know, there is no real requirement for compiling Java code with the latest versions of the language. It is up to you.

Common points to consider:

- Compatibility issues with dependency libraries and frameworks
- Compatibility issues/unsupported binary versions on the target JVM versions
- Known performance (or other improvements) in the newer Java versions.
- Backward compatibility - code compiled with newer Java (e.g. 8) might not always be able to execute on older JVM (e.g. 6).

I would (and I encourage you) to check the release notes to see what changes, improvements, compatibility constraints etc. are introduced in the new JVM version.

Comment: Hi @Ivan: Thanks for your reply. I know it is not required to upgrade the compiler, but is there any performance gain?